# Display gridview only when matching ID's match

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have applied a filter on dropdownlist selected value which matched the `Project_id`, `Building_id` and `flat_id` then **gridview should display other wise  not**.

Now what I want is if ALL the **id** matches then only display the gridview.

Here is my code below:-

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("PROJECT_ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("BUILDING_ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("FLAT_ID");

    DataView dView = new DataView(dt);

    dView.RowFilter = "PROJECT_ID = " + ddlProject.SelectedValue + " AND BUILDING_ID = " + ddlBuilding.SelectedValue + " AND FLAT_ID = " + ddlUnit.SelectedItem.Text;
    GrdBookingStatus.DataSource = dView.ToTable();
    GrdBookingStatus.DataBind();

    DisplayGrid();
    GrdBookingStatus.Visible = true;
```

*Currently it is showing if the ID's doesn't matches also*

what condition should I check ?

`DisplayGrid()`

```
protected void DisplayGrid()
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT pn.property_name, pn.building, cd.flat_id, ab.flat_status, ab.COMMENTS " +
                                           "FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_projbuild_v pn INNER JOIN xxacl_pn_flat_status_his ab " +
                                           "ON pn.project_id = ab.project_id AND pn.building_id = ab.building_id " +
                                           "INNER JOIN xxacl_pn_flat_det_v cd ON cd.flat_id = ab.flat_id", ObjPriCon);
    DataTable dtfillgrid = new DataTable();
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dtfillgrid);
    GrdBookingStatus.DataSource = dtfillgrid;
    GrdBookingStatus.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Why both `PROJECT_ID` and `BUILDING_ID` are checking by `SelectedValue`?

Comment: @AlexJolig: because in the `db` it is getting saved by its value and for `flat` it is coming as `Text` that's why.

Comment: Why are you calling `DisplayGrid();` again? What *exactly* it does?

Comment: @Irshad: In that I have written the code for displaying grid. I need to check condition and then display. See  my updated question

Comment: Your `DisplayGrid()` method reverts back the filter you had and displays all data. You have to work all again to correct it.

Comment: @Irshad: So what should I do, in order to display grid only when all the condition matches ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DisplayGrid()` method reverts back the filter you had and displays all data.

Move the filter inside the `DisplayGrid()` method.

```
protected void DisplayGrid()
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT pn.project_id AS project_id, pn.property_name, pn.building, pn.building_id AS building_id, cd.flat_id AS flat_id, ab.flat_status, ab.COMMENTS " +
                                           "FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_projbuild_v pn INNER JOIN xxacl_pn_flat_status_his ab " +
                                           "ON pn.project_id = ab.project_id AND pn.building_id = ab.building_id " +
                                           "INNER JOIN xxacl_pn_flat_det_v cd ON cd.flat_id = ab.flat_id", ObjPriCon);
    DataTable dtfillgrid = new DataTable();
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dtfillgrid);

    DataView dView = new DataView(dtfillgrid);

    dView.RowFilter = "PROJECT_ID = " + ddlProject.SelectedValue + " AND  BUILDING_ID = " + ddlBuilding.SelectedValue + " AND FLAT_ID = " + ddlUnit.SelectedItem.Text;
    GrdBookingStatus.DataSource = dView.ToTable();
    GrdBookingStatus.DataBind();
    GrdBookingStatus.Visible = dView.ToTable().Rows.Count > 0;
}
```

I've also modified you `SELECT` statement to return `pn.project_id`and `pn.building_id`

Comment: I want to display grid on the `selectedindexchanged` event of the third dropdownlist.

Comment: Call `DisplayGrid()` inside `selectedindexchanged` event.

Comment: getting error as `cannot find column `PROJECT_ID` error

Comment: on `Page_load` i have set `gridview.visible = false`. So shd I need to make it visible after `GrdBookingStatus.DataBind();` ??

Comment: Yes. `GrdBookingStatus.Visible = true;` after `DisplayGrid()`

Comment: but it is showing blank grid if the value doesn't matched. I want to hide if value does not match. what to do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100438/discussion-between-irshad-and-coder).

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddl.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int selectedcheckbox = 0;

            pfPL.Month = lblMonthId.Value;
            pfPL.Year = lblYear.Value;
         
            DataTable dt = pfBL.GetEmployeeCode(pfCPL);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {

                        for (int k = 0; k < grd.Rows.Count; k++)
                        {
                            string grdcode;
                            Label lbl = (Label)grd.Rows[k].FindControl("lblCode");
                            grdcode = lbl.Text;
                            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)grd.Rows[k].FindControl("chkone");
                            e;

                            dbcode = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                            if (dbcode.Trim() == grdcode.Trim())
                            {
                                chk.Checked = true;
                                
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
       
    }
```